# Busqueda y paginacion en php

Tags: php, buscador, paginación

Hola que tal tengo el siguiente problema, estoy trabajando en un proyecto para desarrollar un CRUD ,que entre otras características contenga los elementos de  buscador y paginación; he estado haciendo algunas solo que algo falla durante la operación de búsqueda ya que no consigo que una vez colocado algún dato me realice la búsqueda, por lo que entiendo se estaría compartiendo información de la sección paginado como buscador pero no encuentro el error para dicha conexion adjunto la sección del código:

---

Que tal nuevamente estoy enviando como me comentabas la edición de la pregunta con el código adjunto,  donde ya se encuentra la implementación colocada en el mismo, que amablemente me proporcionaste, como te comentaba solo modifique el fetch que le faltaba al operador.

Lo que sucede es que no aparece nada, solo el encabezado de la tabla, pero sin ningún registro.

---

este es toda la sección del código, la simplifique asi, para que veas como pretendo que sea la salida hacia el navegador.

gracias nuevamente:

---

```
            <div class="">
                        <form action="" class="formulario" method="post">
                        <p><input type="text" id="buscar" name="buscar" placeholder="buscar Nombre o Usuarios"
                        value="<?php if(isset($buscar_text)) echo $buscar_text; ?>" class="input__text">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn"  name="btn_buscar" value="Buscar"></p>
                      </form>
                  <div class=""><h2>Listado de  <b>Usuarios</b></h2></div>
                <div class="">
                  <button id="botones_administrador" onclick="location.href='create_usuarios.php'"><span>Agregar Usuarios</span></button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php
            include_once 'conexion.php';
            $limit = 2;
    // Asignación ternaria para página y términos de búsqueda
    $pag = (isset($_GET['pag'])) ? (int) $_GET['pag'] : 1;
    $buscar = (isset($_GET['buscar'])) ? $_GET['buscar'] : '';
    $filtro = '';
    $params = [];

    // Crear filtro y parámetros si hay algo para buscar
    if($buscar != '') {
        // Dos marcas ?, una para cada campo
        $filtro = ' WHERE nombre_empleado LIKE ? OR usuario LIKE ?';
        // Dos valores, uno para cada marca
        $params = ["%$buscar", "%$buscar"];
    }
    // Preparar consulta para contar
    $contar = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM empleados
            INNER JOIN rol ON empleados.id_rol = rol.id_rol
            $filtro");
    // Ejecutar enviando parámetros
    $contar->execute($params);
    // Leer resultado de consulta
    $contarRow = $contar->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // Obtener total de registros encontrados
    $registros = $contarRow['total'];

    // Hay resultados?
    if($registros > 0) {
        // Calcular página máxima
        $maxPag = ceil($registros / $limit);
        if($page < 1) {
            // Asegurar que página es mayor que cero
            $page = 1;
        } elseif($page > $maxPag) {
            // Asegurar que página no supera la máxima
            $page = $maxPag;
        }
        // Calcular inicio de resultados
        $offset = ($pag - 1) * $limit;
        // Preparar consulta con búsqueda, paginación y orden
        $busqueda = $con->prepare("SELECT empleados.*, rol.tipo_rol FROM empleados
                INNER JOIN rol ON empleados.id_rol = rol.id_rol
                $filtro
                LIMIT $offset, $limit
                ORDER BY id_empleado");
        // Ejecutar consulta enviando parámetros
        $busqueda->execute($params);
        // Recorrer resultados de búsqueda
?>
<tbody>


        <table class="table"><tr class="bg-primary">

                   <th>ID</th>
                   <th>Nombre</th>
                   <th>Primer apellido</th>
                   <th>Segundo apellido</th>
                   <th>Usuario</th>
                   <th>Password</th>
                   <th>Rol</th>
                   <th colspan="2">Acción</th>

    <?php
        while($fila=$busqueda->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    ?>
                 <td><?php echo $fila['nombre_empleado']; ?></td>
                         <td> <?php echo $fila['nombre_empleado']; ?></td>
                         <td> <?php echo $fila['primer_apellido']; ?></td>
                 <td> <?php echo $fila['segundo_apellido']; ?></td>
                 <td> <?php echo $fila['usuario']; ?></td>
                 <td> <?php echo $fila['password']; ?></td>
                         <td> <?php echo $fila['tipo_rol']; ?></td>
                 <td><a href="update_usuarios.php?id_empleado=<?php echo $fila['id_empleado']; ?>"  class="btn__update" >Editar</a></td>
                           <td><a href="delete_usuarios.php?id_empleado=<?php echo $fila['id_empleado']; ?>" class="btn__delete">Eliminar</a></td>
      <?php
            // Aquí muestras los resultados
        }
    }
     ?>
    </tbody>

    </section>
```

Comment: ¿En qué momento colocas `echo $tabla;` o cómo la envías al navegador?

Comment: Gracias, Triby, por tu solución, perdón por contestar tarde pero apenas pude retomar el proyecto, solo me falta corregir la sintaxis de la bd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es buena idea hacer una consulta de todos los campos y filas para contar, es mejor usar [`COUNT(*)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html).

Tampoco es buena idea usar método POST para búsquedas, porque necesitarías un formulario en lugar de enlace para acceder a cada página de resultados, complicando mucho todo el proceso y, además, es casi seguro que el navegador muestre un mensaje pidiendo recargar la página cuando uses el botón "Atrás".

Lo primero que hay que hacer es verificar si se proporcionaron variables en URL, específicamente, página y términos de búsqueda. Con base en esas variables se van a crear consultas para contar y obtener registros a mostrar.

Por seguridad, se usan sentencias preparadas, pero los parámetros no son por nombre, sino por marca `?` y, en lugar de enlazarlos con `bindParam()`, se envían como arreglo al ejecutar la consulta.

```
<?php  

$limit = 2;
// Asignación ternaria para página y términos de búsqueda
$pag = (isset($_GET['pag'])) ? (int) $_GET['pag'] : 1;
$buscar = (isset($_GET['buscar'])) ? $_GET['buscar'] : '';
$filtro = '';
$params = [];

// Crear filtro y parámetros si hay algo para buscar
if($buscar != '') {
    // Dos marcas ?, una para cada campo
    $filtro = ' WHERE nombre_empleado LIKE ? OR usuario LIKE ?';
    // Dos valores, uno para cada marca
    $params = ["%$buscar", "%$buscar"];
}
// Preparar consulta para contar
$contar = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM empleados
        INNER JOIN rol ON empleados.id_rol = rol.id_rol
        $filtro");
// Ejecutar enviando parámetros
$contar->execute($params);
// Leer resultado de consulta
$contarRow = $contar>fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// Obtener total de registros encontrados
$registros = $contarRow['total'];

// Hay resultados?
if($registros > 0) {
    // Calcular página máxima
    $maxPag = ceil($registros / $limit);
    if($page < 1) {
        // Asegurar que página es mayor que cero
        $page = 1;
    } elseif($page > $maxPag) {
        // Asegurar que página no supera la máxima
        $page = $maxPag;
    }
    // Calcular inicio de resultados
    $offset = ($pag - 1) * $limit;
    // Preparar consulta con búsqueda, paginación y orden
    $busqueda = $con->prepare("SELECT empleados.*, rol.tipo_rol FROM empleados
            INNER JOIN rol ON empleados.id_rol = rol.id_rol
            $filtro
            LIMIT $offset, $limit
            ORDER BY id_empleado");
    // Ejecutar consulta enviando parámetros
    $busqueda->execute($params);
    // Recorrer resultados de búsqueda
    while($fila=$busqueda->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        // Aquí muestras los resultados
    }
}
```

Hay comentarios en el código para que sepas cómo funciona cada cosa, pero no dudes en preguntar si algo no quedó claro.

Comment: hola que tal, muchas gracias por responder a mi pregunta, te comento que ya implemente tu respuesta en el código, solo que no me aparece nada, solo los encabezados de la columna, sin ningún registro, según yo solo era colocar los elementos que forman el ciclo while, lo unico que cambie de tu codigo, fue agregar el operador en fetch, ya que le faltaba el guion, de antemano gracias

Comment: @Knight77, perdón, error mío... edita tu pregunta (no la respuesta) con tu código actual, por favor.