# Por que en mi tabla el paginador, solo me muestra hasta donde sale un numero entero?

Tags: php, base-de-datos, paginación, table

No se si me di a explicar, pero aqui lo puedo decir mucho mas facil... Digamos por paginador quiero 5 registros, todo bien ¿No?... pero si tengo 15 registros deberia de mostrar 3 paginas, ahi todo bien... Pero digamos si tengo 18 registros ya me deberia de mostrar 4 paginas, 3 de 5 registros y 1 de 3 registros y he aqui el problema, no me muestra cuando pasa eso... Mi codigo es el siguiente.

```
            $sql_registe = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * from control_acceso");
            $register = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_registe);
            $total_registro = $register['ID_ACCESO'];

            $por_pagina = 5;

            if (empty($_GET['pagina'])) {
                $pagina = 1;
            } else {
                $pagina = $_GET['pagina'];
            }
            $desde = ($pagina - 1) * $por_pagina;
            $total_paginas = ceil($total_registro / $por_pagina);
            echo "$total_paginas";
            //
```

Y mi codigo del paginador es el siguiente.

````
       <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
           <?php
           if ($pagina != 1) {
           ?>
               <li class="page-item">
                   <a class="page-link" href="?pagina=<?php echo 1; ?>" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i></a>
               </li>
               <li class="page-item">
                   <a class="page-link" href="?pagina=<?php echo $pagina - 1; ?>" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
               </li>
           <?php
           }
           for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_paginas; $i++) {
               if ($i == $pagina) {
                   echo '
                          <li class="page-item active"> <span class="page-link">
                       ' . $i . '
                        <span class="sr-only">(current)
                       </span>
                     </span>
                   </li>';
               } else {
                   echo '<li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="?pagina=' . $i . '">' . $i . ' </a>
            </li>';
               }
           }
           if ($pagina != $total_paginas) {
           ?>

               <li class="page-item">
                   <a class="page-link" href="?pagina=<?php echo $pagina + 1; ?>"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
               </li>
               <li class="page-item">
                   <a class="page-link" href="?pagina=<?php echo $total_paginas ?>"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
               </li>
           <?php
           }
           ?>
       </ul>
   </div> ```
````

Comment: ¿Puedes modificar la pregunta y mostrar el resto del código?

Comment: Te refieres a dónde tengo el código del paginador?

Comment: Qué valor te está arrojando **$total_registro**?. En todo caso, yo siendo tú no me fiaría de ese valor, más bien usaría **SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS**. Creo que además deberías especificar de qué va la tabla **control_acceso**.

Comment: Me envia el valor de "3" es decir 3 paginas para mi paginador, pero lo que yo necesito es que me muestre todos, en este caso me faltaria una pagina por que tengo 18 registros y solo me muestra 15, 5 en cada pagina.

Comment: Es más fácil contar el total de registros con la sentencia adecuada. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/392754/busqueda-y-paginacion-en-php/392812#392812) te puede servir de guía.

Comment: No me ayudó, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con algo así, contando tú los registros y no confiando en que los `ID_ACCESO` sean consecutivos. Donde pongo `provincias` utiliza `control de acceso`:

```
<pre>
<?php
// parámetros del paginador
$filas_por_pagina = 5;

// página y primer elemento a mostrar
if(!isset($_GET['pag']))
    $_GET['pag']=0;
$inicio=$_GET['pag']*$filas_por_pagina;

// conexión a la base de datos
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','provincias');

// número de elementos a mostrar
$n_filas=$conn->query("
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM provincias;
")->fetch_row()[0];

// selección de página a mostrar
for($i=0;$i<ceil($n_filas/$filas_por_pagina);$i++)
    echo '<a href="?pag='.$i.'">'.($i+1).'</a> ';

// acceso a los datos
$rs=$conn->query("
    SELECT * FROM provincias
      LIMIT $inicio,$filas_por_pagina;
")->fetch_all();

// visualización de los datos de la página
print_r($rs);
```

Comment: Todo va perfecto, solo que cuando pongo el ciclo for hace que explote mi pagina mandando a numero infinito mi paginador jajajaja

Comment: He arreglado eso, ahora si me manda las 4 paginas que deberian de ser, pero ahora le de al 1 o 2 o 3 o 4 no me cambia de registros

Comment: Es decir, nadamas me muestra mis id del 1 al 5

Comment: Ya lo he aregglado, muchisimas gracias!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Disculpa, no he visto tus comentarios hasta ahora. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 0):

```
//PAGINADOR
        $sql_registe = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * from control_acceso");
        $register = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_registe);
        $total_registro = $register['ID_ACCESO'];

        $por_pagina = 5;

        if (empty($_GET['pagina'])) {
            $pagina = 1;
        } else {
            $pagina = $_GET['pagina'];
        }

        $n_filas = $conexion->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM control_acceso;")->fetch_row()[0];

        $desde = ($pagina - 1) * $por_pagina;
        $total_paginas = ceil($n_filas / $por_pagina);
        echo "$total_paginas";
        //
```

Y mi paginador.

```
<?php
        if ($pagina != 1) {
        ?>
            <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="?pagina=<?php echo 1; ?>" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="?pagina=<?php echo $pagina - 1; ?>" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
            </li>
        <?php
        }

        for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_paginas; $i++) {
            if ($i == $pagina) {
                echo '
                       <li class="page-item active"> <span class="page-link">
                    ' . $i . '
                     <span class="sr-only">(current)
                    </span>
                  </span>
                </li>';
            } else {
                echo '<li class="page-item">
             <a class="page-link" href="?pagina=' . $i . '">' . $i . ' </a>
         </li>';
            }
        }
        if ($pagina != $total_paginas) {
        ?>

            <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="?pagina=<?php echo $pagina + 1; ?>"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="?pagina=<?php echo $total_paginas ?>"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
            </li>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
```